# Rails: Overwrite twitter-bootstrap-rails's generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

how cam i Overwrite/customize the template that is used when I execute `rails g bootstrap:themed [RESOURCE_NAME]` in the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look in the gem (either`bundle open twitter-bootstrap-rails` or look at the GitHub site - https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), you'll see there are generator templates in /lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/templates.

You can overwrite these by having different versions in your app. Make sure you use the same directory structure.

Update

The templates need to live in `lib/templates/bootstrap/themed`

Comment: I worked it out; the correct place for the custom templates is lib/templates/bootstrap/themed